Function satisfying $y(0)=1$ and $y(1)=4$ such that $(y')^2/y<4$ for all $x\in (0,1)$
I am trying to find a function satisfying
$$
y\left(0\right) = 1\quad\mbox{and}\quad y\left(1\right) = 4\quad\mbox{such that}\quad {\left(y'\right)^{2} \over y} < 4\,\, \forall x \in \left(0,1\right)
$$

Does anyone have an idea how to go about this ?.
I tried with building simple functions satisfying the first two conditions such as $4^{x}$ or
$3\sin\left(\pi x/2\right) +1 $ but they all fail to satisfy the last condition.


Think of the antiderivative of $\frac{y'}{\sqrt{y}}$.

$x^2+2x+1$ satisfies the equality (not inequality) with 4. You can maybe take some help from this

@hamam_Abdallah . This would end up being $2\sqrt(y)$. If I put in the start and endpoints 0 and 1 my result is 3 (since $2*\sqrt(4) - 2*\sqrt(1) = 3>2$. Would that mean no answer exists?

If you are looking for a continuous function, MVT guarantees that there will be a point $c$ such as $y'(c)=4, (y'(c))^2=16$. We also know that the values of $y$ will be very close to $1$ around zero. Hence it's not possible to satisfy the third condition.

@Vasili I don’t think that’s true since e.g. 3x+1 is continuous and satisfies conditions 1 and 2 but the derivative is 3 so there is no c s.t. It equals 4.

@Vasili the application of the MVT gives you that $y'(c)=3$, not $4$. Furthermore there is nothing saying that $c$ has to be very close to $0$, so how would this imply the third condition cannot be satisfied?

I would try a piecewise linear function.  For the first part, let y = 1.99x + 1.  Let this work from 0 to 0.5, and then connect the end of that to y(1) = 4.

@Gwen: Well, if a quadratic doesn't work, maybe try a cubic?

Must $y$ be continuous? If so, I agree that there are no solutions. However, as stated, strictly speaking, there's no requirement that $y$ be continuous at the endpoints. So you could easily do something like $$y=\begin{cases}1, &0\le x<1\ 4, &x=1\end{cases}.$$

The "obvious" answer is that maximizing $y'^2/y$ maximizes $y$, so any solution to your problem must be strictly less than the solution to the related IVP
$$ z'^2/z = 4, \quad z(0) = 1 $$
for all $x > 0$. This gives $z = (x+1)^2$, which has $z(1) = 4$. Thus, there is no solution to your problem, as any solution would have $y(1) < z(1) = 4$, which is a contradiction.

Now to address the "obvious" part. I find it easy to convince myself that maximizing that ratio should maximize $y$, but it remains to be proven.
Consider the function
$$ f(x) = \sqrt{z(x)} - \sqrt{y(x)} $$
Since the square root is increasing, if $f(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$, then $z > y$ there as well. Further, if $f'(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$, then surely $f(x) > 0$ there as well. As such, we take the derivative
$$ f'(x) = \frac{z'}{2\sqrt{z}} - \frac{y'}{2\sqrt{y}} $$
Since $z$ satisfies the equality, $z'/2\sqrt{z} = 1$, and since $y$ satisfies the inequality, $y'/2\sqrt{y} < 1$. Thus,
$$ f'(x) = 1 - \frac{y'}{2\sqrt{y}} > 1 - 1 = 0 $$
And with that, we're done.

Case 1: Suppose $y\ge0$ in $[0,1]$. Note
$${(y')^{2} \over y} < 4 $$
is equivalent to
$$ -2<\frac{y'}{\sqrt y}<2. \tag1$$
Integrating from $0$ to $x$ and using $y(0)=1$ give
$$ -x<\sqrt{y(x)}-1<x. $$
Letting $x=1$ and using $y(1)=4$ in the above give $-1<1<1$ which is absurd.
Case 2: Suppose $y$ changes sign in $[0,1]$. Let $x_0$ be the first zero of $y$ in $[0,1]$. Integrating (1) from $0$ to $x_0$ gives
$$ -x_0<\sqrt{y(x_0)}-\sqrt{1}<x_0 $$
which gives
$$ -x_0<-1<x_0$$
which is absurd too.
Thus such function $y$ satisfying the conditions does not exist.

Suppose that $y$ is a polynomial.  The existing answer attempt couldn't get a quadratic polynomial to work, so let's try a cubic.
$$y(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$
$$y'(x) = 3x^2 + 2bx + c$$
The given initial conditions then become:
$$y(0) = 1 \implies d = 1$$
$$y(1) = 4 \implies a + b + c + d = 4 \implies a + b + c = 3$$
So we can reduce the number of coefficients to 2:
$$y(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + (3 - a - b)x + 1$$
$$y'(x) = 3x^2 + 2bx + 3 - a - b$$
Next, let $z(x) = \frac{(y'(x))^2}{y(x)} = \frac{(3x^2 + 2bx + 3 - a - b)^2}{ax^3 + bx^2 + (3 - a - b)x + 1}$.
Plugging in $x = 0$ gives $z(0) = (3 - a - b)^2$.  If we wish to have $z(0) \le 4$, then:
$$a^2 + b^2 + 2ab - 6a - 6b + 9 \le 4$$
$$(a + b)^2 - 6(a + b) + 5 \le 0$$
$$1 \le a + b \le 5$$
Plugging in $x = 1$ gives $z(1) = \frac{(6 + b - a)^2}{4}$.  To have $z(1) \le 4$, we need:
$$a^2 + b^2 - 2ab - 12a + 12b + 36 \le 16$$
$$(b - a)^2 + 12(b - a) + 20 \le 0$$
$$-10 \le b - a \le -2$$
It would be convenient if $a$ and $b$ were integers.  The integer $(a, b)$ pairs that meet both endpoint inequalities are:
$$(a, b) \in \{ (2, -1), (2, 0), (3, -2), (3, -1), (3, 0), (3, 1), (4, -3), (4, -2), (4, -1), (4, 0), (4, 1), (5, -4), (5, -3), (5, -2), (5, -1), (5, 0), (6, -4), (6, -3), (6, -2), (6, -1), (7, -3), (7, -2) \}$$
Brute-forcing the requirement that $z(x) < 4$ where $x$ is a multiple of $10^{-6}$ between $0$ and $1$ reduces this set to 15 values.
$$(a, b) \in \{ (2, -1), (2, 0), (3, -2), (3, -1), (3, 0), (3, 1), (4, -3), (4, -2), (4, -1), (4, 0), (4, 1), (5, -4), (5, -3), (5, -2), (5, -1) \}$$
You'll have to double-check that none of these cubics has $z(x) \ge 4$ somewhere between multiples of $10^{-6}$.
